# Dates and numbers in newspaper articles

Tags: formatting

What is the universal format followed when we write a date in a newspaper article (for example: *24th November*)? I looked around for some examples and didn't find them to be consistent. Is there any hard format at all or is it to the author's discretion? Is it different for different countries and styles, akin to how spellings vary between British English and American English?

Comment: If you looked around and found inconsistent examples, then it stands to reason that there is no "universal format." However, I doubt it's left up to the "author's discretion" – many publications probably have their own formatting standards.

Comment: i don't know about newspapers but there is 2 universal standards when it comes to writing in general, the apa style and the chicago style (well there's also the mla and a bunch of other standards) but as far as i know, the apa is the most widely used, then you have chicago - i think chicago is the standard for newspapers http://www2.liu.edu/cwis/cwp/library/workshop/citation.htm

Answer (score 3):

Newspapers are perhaps the iconic manifestation of "house style."  Several publications have been in print near-continuously since before we had ample standardization of grammar and formats, and are likely the source of several "American" or "British" standards.

If you're writing for an existing publication, inquire with the submission editor for the specific rules they expect of submissions, or examine their printed issues for reference.

If, instead, you're editing a newspaper and want to form a consistent style, consider purchasing the [Associated Press Stylebook](http://www.apstylebook.com/), which has quoted prices between $20 and $30 for various resources.

---

To be more clear, there is no universal style for dates, and such varies both per-country and per-publication.